# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'code'

Tags: flutter, dart

Full error -

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'code'.
> Receiver: "http://download.jimicloud.com/webDown/mibike?no=75039909"
> Tried calling: code)

Hi all! I'm trying to scan the qr code and send the data to the server, but I'm running into the error you see above.

Package for code scanning - qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
Here is my scan widget code -

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_cubit.dart';
import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
// import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import '../home/home.dart';

import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

class MyQr extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ScannerCubit>(
      create: (context) => ScannerCubit(),
      child: QRViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class QRViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QRViewExampleState createState() => _QRViewExampleState();
}

class _QRViewExampleState extends State<QRViewExample> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    print('первая функция');
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      controller!.resumeCamera();
    }
  }

  getQr(qr) {
    if (qr != null) {
      RegExp exp = RegExp(r"[^0-9]+");
      final stringFormat = qr.code.rawContent.replaceAll(exp, '');
      return stringFormat;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ScannerCubit, ScannerState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ScannerNotScan) {
            return SafeArea(
                child: Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: QRView(
                      key: qrKey,
                      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Center(
                      child: (result != null)
                          ? Text(
                              'Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(result!.format)}   Data: ${result!.code}')
                          : Text('Scan a code'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
          } else if (state is ScannerLoading) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          } else if (state is ScannerLoaded) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: Text('Успех!')),
            );
          } else if (state is ScannerError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: Text('Ошибка!')),
            );
          }
          throw StateError('err');
        },
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) async {
    print('последняя функция');
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        if (result != null) {
          getNextScreen();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void getNextScreen() async {
    if (result != null) {
      await context.read<ScannerCubit>().scanner(getQr(result!.code));
      // log(await getQr(result!.code.toString()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And here is my cubit -

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:eco_city/features/data/scanner/scanner_models.dart';
import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../../config.dart';

class ScannerCubit extends Cubit<ScannerState> {
  ScannerCubit? bloc;
  ScannerCubit() : super(ScannerNotScan());

  Future<void> scanner(String qr) async {
    if (isClosed) return;
    emit(ScannerLoading());

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.sendQrCodeScanner),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
          "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          "qr_code": qr,
        }));
    if (isClosed) return;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      log(qr);
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      emit(ScannerLoaded(scannerModel: ScannerModel.fromJson(responseJson)));
    } else {
      log(qr);
      log(response.statusCode.toString());
      log(json.decode(response.body).toString());
      emit(ScannerError());
    }
  }
}
```

I don’t understand at all what the error is, and how can I send ONLY numbers to the server?

and my vscode - [image: vscode]

Answer (score 0):

first print the this line *** log(await getQr(result!.code.toString())) ****
and check whether is function is return the value or returning the null.

Comment: I added a photo, can you check?